# Preventing a Gillespie SSA Stochastic Model From Running Negative

Tags: r, modeling, stochastic, stochastic-process

I have produce a stochastic model of infection (parasitic worm), using a Gillespie SSA. The model used the "GillespieSSA"package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GillespieSSA/index.html). 
In short the code models a population of discrete compartments. Movement between compartments is dependent on user defined rate equations. The SSA algorithm acts to calculate the number of events produced by each rate equation for a given timestep (tau) and updates the population accordingly, process repeats up to a given time point. The problem is, the number of events is assumed Poisson distributed (Poisson(rate[i]*tau)), thus produces an error when the rate is negative, including when population numbers become negative.

```
# Parameter Values 
sir.parms <- c(deltaHinfinity=0.00299, CHi=0.00586, deltaH0=0.0854, aH=0.5,
               muH=0.02, SigmaW=0.1, SigmaM =0.8, SigmaL=104, phi=1.15, f = 0.6674,
               deltaVo=0.0166, CVo=0.0205, alphaVo=0.5968, beta=52, mbeta=7300 ,muV=52, g=0.0096, N=100)
# Inital Population Values
sir.x0 <- c(W=20,M=10,L=0.02)
# Rate Equations
sir.a <- c("((deltaH0+deltaHinfinity*CHi*mbeta*L)/(1+CHi*mbeta*L))*mbeta*L*N"
           ,"SigmaW*W*N", "muH*W*N", "((1/2)*phi*f)*W*N", "SigmaM*M*N", "muH*M*N",
           "(deltaVo/(1+CVo*M))*beta*M*N", "SigmaL*L*N", "muV*L*N", "alphaVo*M*L*N", "(aH/g)*L*N")
# Population change for even
sir.nu <- matrix(c(+0.01,0,0,
                   -0.01,0,0,
                   -0.01,0,0,
                   0,+0.01,0,
                   0,-0.01,0,
                   0,-0.01,0,
                   0,0,+0.01/230,
                   0,0,-0.01/230,
                   0,0,-0.01/230,
                   0,0,-0.01/230,
                   0,0,-0.01/32),nrow=3,ncol=11,byrow=FALSE)
runs <- 10
set.seed(1)

# Data Frame of output
sir.out <- data.frame(time=numeric(),W=numeric(),M=numeric(),L=numeric())
# Multiple runs and combining data and SSA methods 
for(i in 1:runs){
  sim <- ssa(sir.x0,sir.a,sir.nu,sir.parms, method="ETL", tau=1/12, tf=140, simName="SIR")
  sim.out <- data.frame(time=sim$data[,1],W=sim$data[,2],M=sim$data[,3],L=sim$data[,4])

  sim.out$run <- i
  sir.out <- rbind(sir.out,sim.out)
}
```

Thus, rates are computed and the model updates the population values for each time step, with the data store in a data frame, then attached together with previous runs. However, when levels of the population get very low events can occur such that the number of events that occurs reducing a population is greater than the number in the compartment. One method is to make the time step very small, however this greatly increases the length of the simulation very long.

My question is there a way to augment the code so that as the data is created/ calculated at each time step any values of population numbers that are negative are converted to 0?

I have tried working on this problem, but only seem to be able to come up with methods that alter the values once the simulation is complete, with the negative values still causing issues in the runs themselves. 
E.g.
    if (sir.out$L < 0) sir.out$L == 0

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is the method you set ("ETL") in the ssa function. The ETL method will eventually produce negative numbers. You can try the "OTL" method, based on *Efficient step size selection for the tau-leaping simulation method*- in which there are a few more parameters that you can tweak, but the basic command is:

```
ssa(sir.x0,sir.a,sir.nu,sir.parms, method="OTL", tf=140, simName="SIR")
```

Or the direct method, which will not produce negative number whatsoever:

```
ssa(sir.x0,sir.a,sir.nu,sir.parms, method="D", tf=140, simName="SIR")
```